# Email not received

Tags: php, email

I've created a contact form and am sending an email on submission.
Once submitted, I get the 'success' message. however, when I check my email, the message doesn't reach my mailbox.

Here is the form:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." aria-invalid="false">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

contact-me.js:

```
// Contact Form Scripts

$(function() {

    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that our mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

contact-me.php:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

I'm not too sure what is going wrong here, it my just be the server config that might be causing the issue.

Could anyone see where/what I'm going/doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check Spam folder

Comment: you're simply ASSUMING that `mail()` succeeded (hint: it returns boolean false on failure). And even if it did succeed. php's job is the equivalent of running your envelope down to the street corner and tossing it into the mailbox. If the envelope gets lost/destroyed, that's not PHP's problem, it's the postal service's. You need to check the mail server logs as well.

Comment: *Why* do you show the success message? If you remove the mail function you'll continue getting "success", although the message wasn't sent;